# Airflow: Triggering weekly job midweek

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a job that runs every Sunday, and generates a report pertaining to the last X days of data. My task takes in two arguments: the execution date (via template), and lookback X.

However, spur-of-the-moment, I decide I need to generate a similar report TODAY (lets say Wednesday), that uses today as the execution date, but otherwise uses the same logic, and same lookback period X.

Whats the easiest way to trigger such a job on airflow (either CL or webserver) without changing the schedule-interval in the dag-definition? I still want my job to continue running on subsequent Sundays, yet be able to run off-schedule as needed.

Answer (score 1):

On Airflow UI Main Page , there is a **Run button** which you can run a DAG manually. 
It will get the time the moment you click this button as **execution_date** and your DAG will run as expected without intervening the schedule interval. 
[image: Run button]
Also, if you want to see which one you run is manual or scheduled, you go to graph view, and see this dropdown. Might be the easiest way.

[image: Graph view]

Comment: Alright great. I assume this logic holds for weekly schedules as well...
Related question: What if I want to use some other execution date that isn't TODAY but also isn't the last scheduled date?

Comment: if that's the case, you can do what @kaxil suggested. I think its best way to execute it manually on CLI. In my end, I will duplicate the DAG and give it a start_date and end_date. It will run the same logic and will not mess the original DAG 

Also, if you find my answer useful, I will appreciate if you will mark it as the accepted answer. :) Thanks!

Comment: I guess I could try using the CL method. If I run a task from the CL, will it also show up on the tree/graph in the UI (for others to see)? Or just in the logs?
I guess there's no manually trigger a dag on the UI that uses an execution date OTHER than a) datetime.now(), or b) A previous scheduled run-date? Again, assume today is Thursday, the previous scheduled job was last Sunday, and I want to run my job with an execution-date of Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger your DAG manually from the UI or using the **airflow trigger_dag** cli.

Doc: https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#trigger_dag

```
airflow trigger_dag [-h] [-sd SUBDIR] [-r RUN_ID] [-c CONF] [-e EXEC_DATE]
                    dag_id
```